# Using .ajax in jQuery to get JSON data success but no data returned

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to get some JSON data via .ajax() method in jQuery, here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/abc/message.js",
    type: 'GET',
    data: {},
    beforeSend: function(x) {
    if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
        x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
        }
    },
    datatype: 'json',
    success: ajaxSuccess,
    error: ajaxError
});
function ajaxSuccess(data,status){
    alert(status);
    if(data.updatetime > localtime)
    {...}
}
```

`message.js` contains the JSON data I need.
It did call the success function (`ajaxSuccess`), but the data it parsed is an empty string(`""`).

I've read the document provided by jQuery, and googled for similar problems ,but still can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: im confused, your doing a AJAX GET to a Javascript file? (message.js) Shouldnt you be invoking a web service, for example "http://localhost:8080/myservice.asmx/mywebmethod

Comment: @RPM1984  i don't do the server side stuff, i'm asked to deal with the json data that's going to be sent to the browser, but the server is not available by now. So I just put some sample into the .js file. and placed it in a tomcat server. Is is OK?

Comment: @Sam Saffron♦ firebug return a 200 status but with a red cross following and nothing else...that is confusing....

Comment: What's your json data looks like?

Comment: @Reigel {
 "updatetime":"20100806123500",
 "message":[
  {
   "name":"Tom",
   "id":"1234",
   "posttime":"20100806123030",
   "content":"What a wonderful day!"
  },
  {
   "name":"Jack",
   "id":"3234",
   "posttime":"20100806122931",
   "content":"Screw you Tom....."
  }
         ]
     }

Comment: @calmire - your json is good, so maybe try changing the name of filename `message.js`. maybe something like `message.php`

Comment: id say its the web server not being able to serve http requests to file type ".js". you'd have to configure IIS (or tomcat) to do this. if you put  http://localhost:8080/abc/message.js into your browser - what happens?

Comment: @Reigel scince I'm using tomcat, I changed the filename to message.jsp, and firebug returns no more error message. But the data pass to ajaxSuccess() is still empty...:'(

Comment: @RPM1984 The browser would just display it as plain text.btw, i dont know much about tomcat, could you tell me where to configure this?

Comment: @calmire, is the page `message.jsp` same domain of the page doing ajax? is the page calling ajax is in `http://localhost:8080/` domain?

Comment: @calmire: Are you familiar with Tomcat? If you arent i would try just using in straight up Apache or IIS.

Comment: @Reigel nope..the page doing ajax is in a local directory, such as: "e:\xxx\home.html"

Comment: @prodigitalson no,i'm not familiar with Tomcat. Should i configure the response header in tomcat?

Comment: @calmire, the location explains it. your doing a cross-domain request. please read this [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: @calmire: First of all if youre access the file via `file://` by doing `File Open` in your browser.. thats problem one. Unless youve set up some kind of proxy to make external requests the files need to be on the same domain, ie. `localhost` i dont think files accessed using `file://` are considered part of this in terms of cross domain restrictions. Secondly, i dont know squat about tomcat but its possible its a configuration issue, thus my to just drop everything in folder served by IIS or Apache which you should be able to easily set up to test this.

Comment: @Reigel @prodigitalson I got it. But I don't understand: if it's against the rule, why .ajax() still called the success funtion, and firebug returns no more error messages?

Comment: @Reigel @prodigitalson Guys, you are right. I put all the stuff into a same folder ,and it works fine now. Thank you all!

Comment: @calmire, success means that the page is accessible. try putting a file adrress that is not there and you'll get an error.